How do US self defence law apply to protest camps?
In the US self defence laws appear somewhat on the side of the defender, particularly when ones home is attacked, compared to the UK for example.
These has been an example where third parties, ie. not law enforcement or university authorities, attacked a protest camp in University of California, Los Angeles.  In the hypothetical where this was the protesters homes, say the university halls of residence, I think the defenders would be allowed to use force, up to and including lethal force, to defend themselves and the attackers would not.  In the actual situation, where this is not their home, they are staying there overnight, it is definitely against university regulations, it may or may not be breaking a state law, and it is clear who is the aggressor and who the defender, how would these rules apply?  Would the defenders have greater latitude to use force than the attackers?
As a more concrete example, if one got into a stick fight and kept hitting the other person around the head while they were on the ground until they stop moving that would be illegal in just about any situation in the UK. I think this would be legal for the defender but not the attacker in a case of home invasion in the US.  If this happened in this protest camp, say at the site where the defender was sleeping, would it be legal for either the attacker or defender in this case?

Even in US states where you're allowed to use deadly force to subdue a threat in your home, afaik you're not technically allowed to continue with your vigorous defense of your home once you've subdued the threat.

For clarity, there is not a single U.S. law of self-defense. There are material differences in the law of self-defense between U.S. states in ways pertinent to this question.

The fundamental idea of self-defense is simple: If someone attacks you, you may use the necessary amount of force to defend yourself against that attack.
The location being your home can matter in two ways:
One is that in some jurisdictions already the fact that an intruder is in your home may constitute sufficient grounds for the use of force against them. Otherwise, the bar of arguing that the other person is indeed attacking you is significantly higher. In the case of a protest camp, it certainly wouldn't count as an attack if a person enters a protest camp against the wishes of the protesters. If they start using violence against the protesters, it would.
The other difference is whether the defender has to consider retreat as an option when figuring out whether force is a suitable defense. In some jurisdictions the answer is always yes, in others always no, and in some places you would have to retreat (if possible) in a public space, but not in your own home.
